# .htaccess how to serve contents from different directory for mobile and desktop?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two version of my site. one is a mobile version and another one is desktop.

Path looks like this :

For Mobile : `public_htm/mobile`

For Desktop : `public_html`

I want to change the document root of my domain based on the device. I want to serve content from the `mobile` folder if the user's device is mobile & serve contents from public_html if user on desktop.

How can I do this with `.htaccess`?

I want to have my domain the same for both desktop and mobile, only document root changed by `.htaccess` based on the device.

Comment: What does "based on device" mean?   Do you have different URLs for different devices (like a `m.` subdomain) or are you looking to identify devices based on their user agent string?

Comment: You will find hundreds of existing answers to similar questions here on SO. I suggest that you check those.

Comment: yes based on user agent, i don't want m.example.com, i need only same domain.

Comment: What you are referring to as the "web", you really mean "desktop" (the opposite of "mobile").

Comment: yes opposite of mobile.

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice.  Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add something like the following to the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Prevent direct access to the "/mobile" subdirectory
# - redirect back to the root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^mobile/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L] 

# Rewrite all requests from mobile devices to the "/mobile" site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^iphone|android|etc$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!mobile/).* mobile/$0 [L]
```

The mobile detection regex (`RewriteCond` directive) is just an example, the specifics are left up to the reader. (For reference: [mobile browser user-agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?typ=Mobile%20Browser))

The *negative lookahead* in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* prevents requests that have already been rewritten to the `/mobile` subdirectory from being repeatedly rewritten. If you have another `.htaccess` in the `/mobile` subdirectory containing mod-rewrite directives then this may be unnecessary.

The first rule redirects any direct traffic to the `/mobile` subdirectory back to the document root. However, if you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/mobile` subdirectory containing mod-rewrite directives then this redirect would need to be moved to that `.htaccess` file (it won't work here).

---

Just a note on terminology... This doesn't strictly change the "document root", as mentioned in the question. (Although it might "look like" it does from a client perspective.) This internally rewrites requests to a subdirectory (URL-rewriting). Server-side applications running in the `/mobile` subdirectory still see the document root as being the parent directory. You cannot change the "document root" in `.htaccess`, which can only be done by setting the `DocumentRoot` (or `VirtualDocumentRoot`) directive(s) in the server config.